# Can Scala 2.11.12 compiler on JDK11 produce bytecode for target jvm11?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, bytecode, java-11

Have a project that uses java 8 and scala 2.11.12 and depends on spark 2.4.2.
I need to compile and run this project using jdk11 (Java version: 11.0.12, vendor: Eclipse Foundation)
My scala-maven-plugin config:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
 <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>4.0.1</version>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <phase>compile</phase>
    <goals>
     <goal>compile</goal>
     <goal>add-source</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
 </executions>
 <configuration>
  <args>
    <arg>-target:jvm-1.8</arg>
  </args>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If I compile and run it without any change just using jdk11 I get bytecode version 52. Almost everything is fine and works. Just need to override xbean-asm6-shaded library with new version - 4.10 because old version (bundled with a spark) somehow find bytecode 55 and throw an exception.

When I change target to -target:jvm-1.11 or -target:jvm-11 I get the error:

```
[ERROR] 'jvm-1.11' is not a valid choice for '-target'
[ERROR] bad option: '-target:jvm-1.11'
```

So there is the question:
Can scala compiler 2.11.12 or 2.12.14 produce jdk11 target?

Comment: According to the [JDK compatibility matrix](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html), both compiler versions should be compatible with JDK 11.

Comment: @HristoIliev I saw this matrix. 
Now I can compile my code using JDK11 and run it on JRE8 - bytecode version 52.
But I can't find out why I can't compile my code using JDK11 to target jvm-11 to get bytecode version 55 (incompatible with JRE8).

Comment: Spark v2.4.2 won't run on JDK 11. You need Spark v3+.